# VDM's update not updating data on S/4

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We are using `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.services.DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service` for updating an item on S/4. Please find the code snippet below:

```
DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service service = new DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service();

service.updateOutbDeliveryItem(
     OutbDeliveryItem.builder()
        .deliveryDocument("some key")
        .deliveryDocumentItem("some key")
        .actualDeliveryQuantity(BigDecimal.TEN)
        .build()
).execute(someDestination);
```

This code gets executed successfully, but no update takes place on S/4. While examining the logs, I found following:

`Update strategy is to modify with PATCH, but no fields have changed. The request may be bound to fail in the target system.`

What is the cause of this problem? I've clearly made changes to `actualDeliveryQuantity` field. Why is the update not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No fields have changed" because you edited an offline entity instance, that you've just built yourself.

To get your example working little adjustments have to made:

```java
OutbDeliveryItem item =  OutbDeliveryItem.builder()
  .deliveryDocument("some key")
  .deliveryDocumentItem("some key")
  .build();

// The following method registers a change of the entity.
item.setActualDeliveryQuantity(BigDecimal.TEN);

// Then execute the actual update operation, which only uses the actually changed fields.
service
  .updateOutbDeliveryItem(item)
  .execute(someDestination);
```

If the service is complaining about missing ETag provided, either follow the example described further below using the *get-by-key* appraoch. Or you explicitly tell the request to ignore the version identifer:

```java
service
  .updateOutbDeliveryItem(item)
  .ignoreVersionIdentifier()
  .execute(someDestination);
```

That's it!

---

Alternatively, in order to implement the complete OData update workflow, you need to first get the entity by using the *get-by-key* method as described below.

```java
String deliveryDocument;
String deliveryDocumentItem;
HttpDestinationProperties someDestination;

// First get the item by key.
OutbDeliveryItem item = service
  .getOutbDeliveryItemByKey(deliveryDocument, deliveryDocumentItem)
  .execute(someDestination)

// The following method registers a change of the entity.
itme.actualDeliveryQuantity(BigDecimal.TEN);

// Then execute the actual update operation, which only uses the actually changed fields.
service.updateOutbDeliveryItem(item).execute(someDestination);
```

This way, the ETag will be set internally. The entity version identifier is a requirement for most S/4 OData services to enable update/delete operations.

**Note:** You are not limited to *get-by-key*. You can also use the *get-all* method with filters to resolve multiple entities, in preparation for further update changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! Since I was only using builder, it was only creating an entity and was not registering any changes in the fields.